# Can Damage Multiplier and Predetermined Damage be combined?

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy, ki-techniques

Note: This question is based on something I saw built with the Dominus Exxet Ki Techniques, not the core book Ki Techniques, but I believe that there's no difference at the level this question gets into.

Someone I know recently claimed that Damage Multiplier and Predetermined Damage stack, e.g. that if you have Predetermined Damage 250, and Damage Multiplier 3x, that the Base Damage of your Ki Technique is now 750.

This *seems* patently absurd, but the rules, as usual, don't seem to be clear either way.

Is this the case?

Answers should preferably lean as close to rules as written as possible, though subjective answers aren't off the table.

Answer (score 1):

The only statement in the book is that damage multiplier goes before adding any extra damage, so rules as written, yes, you should be able to combine predetermined damage and multiplier.

It takes a lot of Ki, and a lot of accumulation, but yes, you should be able to pull it of. You should also be able to combine it with area of effect, range attack, armour destruction, base attack... to create an ultimate technique, that will take you hours to accumulate, it will create all the environmental effects described in the book (including losing at least half of them if you go beyond 120)

Comment: Additionally, even given a HUGE damage number, the attack throw is still the number that really really matters. If I saw something like this coming, I'd be dumping my fatigue and declaring total defensive. That or trying to force you to lose your action that turn.

Comment: Totally agree there, Attack is usually better than damage. But usually this god-killer techniques are aided by the party to help the character to be not doing much for a couple of turns, to beat some kind of final boss or something.

Comment: Yeah, the situation given was a god-technique sort of thing, I was just asking about this particular aspect thereof.